# values changed when UITableview is scrolled up or down

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, ios9

I have a `UITableview` and it has some History in it. Im using Custom Cell to handle the display of Labels, Images and buttons. There are around 50 rows inside the `UITableview`. But problem is when the Tableview is scrolled up, then the row below the first displayed ones have the values changed in it. Not sure what exactly is happening with the Tableview.

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"HistoryCell";
cellHistory = [self.notificationTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

[cellHistory.label clearActionDictionary];
//Step 2: Define a selection handler block
void(^handler)(FRHyperLabel *label, NSString *substring) = ^(FRHyperLabel *label, NSString *substring)
{
    [self userNameTapped:[[[[self.arrayHistory objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:Details] objectForKey:@"key"] objectForKey:@"key"]];
};

//Step 3: Add link substrings
[cellHistory.label setLinksForSubstrings:@[userName] withLinkHandler:handler];
return cellHistory;
```

Comment: Please provide more code how do you setting data into your cells.

Comment: I have updated my code above.

Comment: Your cells are being reused. Fundamental iOS design knowledge. Plenty of examples online

Comment: I'm seeing similar behaviour on iOS 9.1 / x-code 7.1. For me this isn't just a cell reuse problem. I'm not having problems in iOS 8.4 though.

Comment: When I had a look at the indexPaths passed to cellForRowAtIndexPath, there are rows that are being updated incorrectly that cellForRowAtIndexPath is not being called for.

Comment: Same issue with me too, there are rows that are being updated incorrectly that cellForRowAtIndexPath is not being called. Since I have a lot of datas in the Tableview I'm reusing the cells within. Reusing should not be having any issues I guess.

Comment: When you scroll the table, each cell scrolled into view is set up in cellForRowAtIndexPath:. I assume the code that you showed is in this method, and when you say „the row … have the values changed“ then you mean cellHistory.label has an unexpected value. But this value is apparently set by clearActionDictionary. So, what does this method do?

Comment: See this related answer. There is a demo app showing how to properly reuse cells without conflict: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34079027/218152

Answer (score 8):

## Beware

The following answer addresses the specific implementation, not the design. Using boilerplate code for `NSFetchedResultsController` would prevent this bug to occur in the first place. ([Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreData/Reference/NSFetchedResultsController_Class/)). At all costs, avoid manipulating a cell once returned by `cellForRowAtIndexPath`: you do *not* own it.

---

**1. Reused Cells are not cached**

Of particular worry is the line:

```
[self.arrayHistory objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]
```

not so much because of that particular instance, but because it leads me to think that you are making assumptions elsewhere in this class: a `UITableViewCell` retrieved via `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` is nothing but a transient object, to be used purely but the `UITableView` for display.

**The very same cell instance will have multiple indexPath over time**: such a cell may **not** be cached or manipulated at a further date. Once returned as the last statement of `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, it may **not** be accessed again, whether retained by an external pointer of through some asynchronous method. Always consider the index path of a cached table view obtained via `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` as **stale**.

Do **not** modify the content of a cell once returned. Follow proper design as outlined by [Losiowaty](https://stackoverflow.com/users/765298/losiowaty) below.

Against better judgement, if you must modify the content of a cell already returned to the table view, then you must dedicate a persistent cell for that, using, for example, a dictionary of `UITableViewCell`. You may not invoke `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` on such a cell unless that identifier is dedicated to that very cell ; while highly memory inefficient for large data sets, it will guarantee that cell are not re-used.

---

**2. Do not guess the `tableview`**

```m
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    cellHistory = [self.notificationTableView // etc.
```

The proper logic in `UITableViewDataSource` `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is to use the parameter passed to you:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    cellHistory = [tableView // etc.
```

---

**3. Reuse clean recycled cells**

Assuming you have mastered the recycling side effects of using `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier`, and ensured that you are not cross pollinate different type of cells, you may want to [cleanup](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewCell_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableViewCell/prepareForReuse) your reused cell *(credit to [Timur Bernikowich](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1980246/timur-bernikowich) for his comment)*:

```swift
func prepareForReuse() {
    super.prepareForReuse()
    // reset attributes of the cell that are not related to content
}
```

---

**4. Introspect first**

Always prefer the tack of *what am I doing wrong* to *it used to work in the previous OS*. While the second proposition is often true, by and large, history lets you ponder on how in heaven it used to work in the first place.

To the contrary, I generally take these situations as a sure sign I was doing something horribly wrong, and I was just lucky to fall through the cracks.

---

**5. Respect naming conventions**

While I admire your passing of blocks in the method

```
- (void)setLinksForSubstrings:(NSArray*)string withLinkHandler:(void(^)(FRHyperLabel *label, NSString *substring))handler {}
```

I was a bit thrown off by nature of the `Details` object or the `userName`, not to mention the 4 brackets in `[self userNameTapped:[[[[`. If I am thrown off, chances are other engineers will, when first being exposed to your code.

From the context, I cannot derive what are variables, constants, statics, instance properties, and so on. It is quite possible your cells are being confused at that level as well (you may be reusing values you assume being locals or stack based, but aren't).

May I suggest using a `typedef` for the block, adopt capitalization consistency, and refrain from nesting `[` too deep. It took a non trivial effort to compare your code with boilerplate `UITableView` code, only to trim out the noise.

Comment: I have to disagree about dedicating a persistent cell in case of need for modification. A much clearer way to do this would be to modify the data in your model and then call `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:`, or the similar method for reloading sections.

Comment: I am in full agreement. I thought item 1. was pretty explicit about not hanging on to returned `UITableViewCell`. I've added a reference to your comment.

Comment: Isn't `prepareForReuse` called by `UITableView`?

Comment: @SwiftArchitect `Discussion
If a UITableViewCell object is reusable—that is, it has a reuse identifier—this method is invoked just before the object is returned from the UITableView method dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:.`