# Updating cell height after image downloads

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiimageview, grand-central-dispatch

I am displaying some text and images in a `UITableView`. The image first gets downloaded. Since before the image gets downloaded, I don't know the size of image, so I initially put a `UIImageView` of some fixed size. And when the image is downloaded, I resize the `UIImageView`.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

// Download image

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

    // UIImageView resizing  
    });  
});
```

All this happens in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.
The issues I am facing here are :
1. How do I update the height of cell ? Considering that there can be many images in a single cell. So I need to change the position of bottom image when above one downloads.
2. I tried using `UITableView` `beginUpdates` and `endUpdates`, but that scrolls to the top of cell giving a poor user experience.

This is how the UI looks like on reloadData. There are 5 images to be downloaded : [**UI experience after UITableView reloadData**](https://youtu.be/8RRVOsRVy1o)

Comment: `beginUpdates` and `endUpdates` is no effect in this case actually *You should not call reloadData within the group* says the documentation.

Comment: @HarikrishnanT : Yes. Gives poor UI experience.

Comment: I had faced the same problem once. The problem is, if you reload just one row, the cell right below it will get hidden behind it, since its frame won't change. I soled it using reloadData then, it worked smoothly. Not sure what is the UX issue in your case.

Comment: @HarikrishnanT : Please check the video I have uploaded on the link. It shows the UI experience on reloadData.

Comment: Why not use `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:` ?

Comment: @KudoCC : That creates scrolling issues.

Comment: @Nitish: are you using autoLayout

Answer (score 22, accepted):

## Short Answer

- Give enough breathing space to `estimatedRowHeight`
- Changing a `UITableViewCell` once returned by `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` will **not** work with cached cells
- Trigger a single cell reload with `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths`
- Manage your cache with Core Data and let `NSFetchedResultsController` boilerplate code can do all the UI work.

---

## In Details

**No unexpected scroll, only updates images as they come:**

1. If the cell being refreshed is **at** or **below** the horizon, the `UITableView` will **not** scroll
2. if the cell being refreshed is **above** the top, the `UITableView` will **not** scroll
3. the `UITableView` will only scroll when the cell is in plain sight, *and* requires more space than available.

**Let `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` do the hard work**

You need to tell Cocoa Touch that the cell is *stale*, so that it will trigger a **new** `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier`, to which you are going to return a **cell** with the proper height.
Short of reloading the entire table view or one of its section, and assuming that your indexes are stable, invoke `-tableView:reloadRows:at:with:` passing the indexPath of the cell that just changed, and a `.fade` animation.

**Code:**

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 250 // match your tallest cell
    tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}
```

Use `URLSession`. When an image becomes available, fire `reloadRows:at:with`:

```
func loadImage(_ url: URL, indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let downloadTask:URLSessionDownloadTask =
        URLSession.shared.downloadTask(with: url, completionHandler: {
        (location: URL?, response: URLResponse?, error: Error?) -> Void in
        if let location = location {
            if let data:Data = try? Data(contentsOf: location) {
                if let image:UIImage = UIImage(data: data) {
                    self.cachedImages[indexPath.row] = image // Save into the cache
                    DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: { () -> Void in
                        self.tableView.beginUpdates()
                        self.tableView.reloadRows(
                            at: [indexPath],
                            with: .fade)
                        self.tableView.endUpdates()
                    })
                }
            }
        }
    })
    downloadTask.resume()
}
```

Once in the cache, `cellForRow` merely reads into it from the UI thread:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "id") as! CustomCell
    cell.imageView.image = cachedImages[indexPath.row]      // Read from the cache
    return cell
}
```

---

*Example: fetch a random set of images from *Wikipedia**

[image: Xcode demo]

► Find this solution on [GitHub](https://github.com/SwiftArchitect/SO-33975355) and additional details on [Swift Recipes](https://github.com/SwiftArchitect/SO-33975355).

Comment: In this case do I need to call heightForRowAtIndex ?

Comment: No. You will see in the linked Xcode project that none of the legacy height calculations are necessary. AutoLayout does **all** the work. It's magical.

Comment: If I am right, auto layout has not been implemented in the code for table cell. Does this suggest, I need to create cell subviews using auto layout for this to work ? Or that is not required.

Comment: Plus one for the sample code. It works as I want it should. But want clarification on above comment

Comment: Using legacy methods, including `heightForRowAtIndexPath` will be invoked when you supply a new cell. But the spurious scrolling is caused by the table view not knowing where to land when you swap cells. I can only speak about `estimatedRowHeight` + `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` combination to prevent such flicker.

Comment: I think you should include all necessary code in the answer; you're not reading from the cache despite storing data into it.

Comment: Writing into the cache in `loadImage`, reading from the cache in `cellForRowAt`. Commented the code for clarification. All necessary code for this answer is in `viewDidLoad`, the entire project is merely there to prove correctness.

Comment: This seems very memory inefficient. All of the images are loaded into the RAM as the "cachedImages" is just a property of the tableView.

Meaning a large amount of records in the tableview might cause your app to run out of Memory.

Please correct me if I'm wrong.