# Cell height not being calculated properly because of Completion Handler

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, autolayout, constraints

I have a cell which has an image in it that is retrieved from Amazon S3. The height of this image will affect the height of the cell but unfortunately the image is retrieved in a completion handler after the cell height is determined. If I scroll down and up the cell reloads properly.

Before scrolling (incorrect cell height):
[image]

After scrolling (correct cell height):
[image]

Cell configuration (some unnecessary stuff redacted for readability):

```
func setCompletionCell(completion: CompletionPublic, contentType: String, classType: String){
        self.completionPub = completion
        self.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.None //Disables clicking

        //Setting image or video
        if (contentType == "image"){
            nwa.fetchSignedUrl("image/accepted/" + completion.mediaId + ".png") { (result, err) in
                self.nwa.fetchImage(result) { (image, err) in

                    if image != nil{
                        let screenSize: CGRect = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds

                        var multiplyNum = screenSize.width / image.size.width
                        //if image height is going to be more than 60% of the screen, resize width and height to ensure that it isn't greater than 60% while keeping the aspect ratio correct
                        if ((image.size.height*multiplyNum) > (screenSize.height*0.6)){
                            multiplyNum = screenSize.height*0.6 / image.size.height
                            self.imageViewWidthConstraint.constant = (multiplyNum*image.size.width)
                            self.imageViewHeightConstraint.constant = screenSize.height*0.6
                        }
                        else{
                            self.imageViewWidthConstraint.constant = screenSize.width
                            self.imageViewHeightConstraint.constant = (multiplyNum*image.size.height)
                        }
                        self.imgView.image = image

                    }
                    else{
                        //no image returned
                    }


                }
            }
        }
        else if (contentType == "video"){
            ytplayer.loadWithVideoId(completion.mediaId)
        }


    }
```

TableView delegate methods:

```
func callNWT(tableView: UITableView, completionHandler: () -> ()) {
    switch trendingToggle {
    case 0:
        nwt.getTrendingBounties(0) { (bountyArr, err) in
            //@TODO: change pos
            if bountyArr == nil {
                self.bountyArr = []
            }
            else {
                self.bountyArr = bountyArr as [BountyPublic]
            }

            if self.bountyArr.count == 0 {
                completionHandler()
            }
            self.reloadTableViewContent(tableView)
        }
    case 1:
        nwt.getTrendingCompletions(0) { (compArr, err) in
            if compArr == nil {
                self.compArr = []
            }
            else {
                self.compArr = compArr as [CompletionPublic]
            }
            if self.compArr.count == 0 {
                completionHandler()
            }
            self.reloadTableViewContent(tableView)
        }
    case 2:
        nwt.getTrendingPeople(0) { (peopleArr, err) in
            if peopleArr == nil {
                self.peopleArr = []
            }
            else {
                self.peopleArr = peopleArr as [Person]
            }

            if self.peopleArr.count == 0 {
                completionHandler()
            }
            self.reloadTableViewContent(tableView)
        }
    default:
        break
    }
}

func configureTableView(tableView: UITableView){
    tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 500.0
    tableView.allowsSelection = false; //disables selection highlighting of cells
    tableView.tableFooterView = UIView()
    tableView.dataSource = self
}

func reloadTableViewContent(tableView: UITableView) {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
        tableView.reloadData()
        print("reloading table view content")
        tableView.scrollRectToVisible(CGRectMake(0, 0, 1, 1), animated: false)
    })
}


func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if trendingToggle == 0 {
        return bountyArr.count
    }
    else if trendingToggle == 1 {
        return compArr.count
    }
    else {
        return peopleArr.count
    }
}


func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if trendingToggle == 0 {
        return bountyCellAtIndexPath(tableView, indexPath: indexPath)
    }
    else if trendingToggle == 1 {
        return completedCellAtIndexPath(tableView, indexPath:indexPath)
    }
    else {
        return personCellAtIndexPath(tableView, indexPath: indexPath)
    }
}

func completedCellAtIndexPath(tableView: UITableView, indexPath:NSIndexPath) -> CompletedCell{
    var cell: CompletedCell
    if compArr[indexPath.row].contentType == "image" {
        cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(completedImgCellIdentifier) as! CompletedCell
        let comp = compArr[indexPath.row]
        cell.setCompletionCell(comp, contentType: "image", classType: "trending")
    }
    else { //video
        cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(completedVidCellIdentifier) as! CompletedCell
        let comp = compArr[indexPath.row]
        cell.setCompletionCell(comp, contentType: "video", classType: "trending")
    }
    return cell
}
```

How do I ensure the cell height is correctly calculated the first time? Is there a way I can delay the code executing until the image is retrieved? Or is that not a good idea?

Comment: post some code, your table view delegate methods and cell configuration.

Comment: You should never pause main queue for network requests. What you should do is after setting image you have to notify table view to layout subviews.

Comment: You can find example code for this here

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33975355/updating-cell-height-after-image-downloads

Comment: You should save the downloaded image locally and then reload the cell with the image in the completion handler, using "reload rows at index path" tableview delegate method.

Comment: What if there are hundreds/thousands of images? Should I still download them locally? @Nishant

Comment: @Mitchell Yes. otherwise you won't be able to give a seemless user experience. If storage is an issue, you can delete these images at the later stage.

Answer (score 1):

Reload the tableview in completion handler.

`tableView.reloadData()`

In the `heightForRowAtIndex` method for the datasource/delegate protocols recalculate the height using the image and return the appropriate value for each individual cell.

When you call reloadData() all the datasource/delegate methods are called again, so return the correct height will allow you to resize the cell as needed.

Comment: Reloading the tableview wont work unless the images are locally saved and retrieved. Also, you can just reload that cell rather than reloading the whole table again and again.

Comment: you're correct the whole tableView dosn't need to be reloaded - just the row in question but why does the image need to be saved locally? (I assume you mean within the app bundle). Why can't you retrieve the image from the server store it in an array in the datasource delegate, and call (whichever) reloadTableView method you like and then in the heightForRowAtIndex method return the height of the image corresponding to the indexPath.row in the array of images?

Comment: Solved by saving locally and then calling tableView.reloadData() and not fetching the image from S3 again. Thanks @Nishant and Blake.

Comment: @Mitchell: Great. I recommend you use         `tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Automatic)` instead of `tableView.reloadData()` in the completion handler.